# Join two tables with WHERE clause with two conditions and not having a condition

Tags: mysql, sql

So I want to get all the antenas that have the band 800 and the band 900 and DO NOT have the band 1500 and DO NOT have the band 2500 with these two tables:

Table antenas:

```
id
-------------
antena_1
antena_2
antena_3
antena_4
antena_5
```

Table bands:

```
antena_id             band
--------------------------
antena_1               800
antena_1               900
antena_1              1500
antena_1              2500
antena_2               800
antena_2               900
antena_2              1500
antena_3               800
antena_3               900
antena_3              1500
antena_3              2500
antena_4               800
antena_4               900
antena_5               800
antena_5              1500
antena_6               800
antena_7               800
antena_7               900
antena_7              3500
```

So the query has to return the antenas: antena_4 and antena_7

I have tried this but it does return antenas that do not have the 1500 bands:

```
SELECT * FROM antenas INNER JOIN bands ON antenas.id = bands.antena_id WHERE

NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT antena_id FROM bands AS innerBands
    WHERE innerBands.antena_id = antenas.id AND (
        bands.band = "1500" OR bands.band = "2500"
    )
)

AND band = "800" AND band = "900"

GROUP BY antenas.id
ORDER BY antenas.id ASC
```

I wonder if the NOT EXISTS does anything at all sinde its in a WHERE and I think I may have to use HAVING as it is a joint table.

I'm pretty clueless at this point after trying lots of stuff.

Comment: Hi!
Wouldn't you like to improve your database designing. I think you could use different table for each antena_1/2/3 which could have the band values. Then it would be easier for you to query depending your demands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use aggregation:

```
select antenna_id
from bands
group by antenna_id
having sum(band = 800) > 0 and
       sum(band = 900) > 0 and
       sum(band = 1500) = 0 and
       sum(band = 2500) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
select a.antena_id
from bands a
join bands b on b.antena_id = a.antena_id and b.band = 900
left join bands c on c.antena_id = a.antena_id and c.band = 1500
left join bands d on d.antena_id = a.antena_id and d.band = 1500
where a.band = 800
  and c.antena_id is null
  and d.antena_id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use inner query

```
SELECT distinct(antenna_id)
FROM bands
WHERE
   band in (800, 900)
   AND antenna_id NOT IN (select antenna_id from bands where band in (1500, 2500));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select b.antena_id, * from antena a
right outer join bands b on a.id = b.antena_id 
where b.band not in (1500, 2500)
    and b.band in (800, 900)
```

[image]